# Function for string column values comparison in RedShift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, sql-like

I'm using [ilike](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-similar-to.html) for column string case insensitive comparison in Redshift. To better handle the string size I do

```
select *
    from testset t
    join predictions p
    on p.id = c.id and
    c.text ilike '%'+p.text+'%'

union

select *
    from testset t
    join predictions p
    on p.id = c.id and
    p.text ilike '%'+c.text+'%'
```

in order to consider length(c) > length(p) and viceversa. By the way, the like has several limitations, like when

```
p.text = "TOKEN1 TOKEN2 TOKEN3"
c.text = "TOKEN1 TOKEN3"
```

it will not work.
I was thinking then to use a [Redshift function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html) (or python function), but I'm not sure how I can support things like Levenshtein distance, string similarity (with threshold), etc. in that function (and if it is possibile), using available libraries for [UDF Python Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html).

My take looks like right now

```
create or replace function f_compare(a VARCHAR, b VARCHAR) returns float IMMUTABLE as $$
    def diff(strL, strR):
        from difflib import SequenceMatcher
        ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, strL, strR).ratio()
        return ratio
    return diff(a,b)
    return f_compare(a,b)
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;  

with samples as (
    select 
    cast('TOKEN1 TOKEN3' as VARCHAR) as name,
    cast('TOKEN1 TOKEN2 TOKEN3' as VARCHAR) as name1
)

select f_compare(name, name1) from samples
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the python libraries instead of writing your own. [TheFuzz](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz) is a pretty popular one.

> It uses Levenshtein Distance to calculate the differences between sequences in a simple-to-use package.

UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION fuzzy_test (string_a TEXT,string_b TEXT) RETURNS FLOAT IMMUTABLE
AS
$$
  FROM fuzzywuzzy import fuzz 
  RETURN fuzz.ratio (string_a,string_b) 
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Query

```
SELECT fuzzy_test('brooklyn bridge', 'brooklin bridge');
-- Output
-- 93
```

You'll have to import that library into your redshift cluster though. Download the fuzzywuzzy repo from [github](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz), zip it, upload it to your S3 and create a library using it.

```
CREATE LIBRARY fuzzywuzzy LANGUAGE plpythonu FROM 's3://<bucket_name>/fuzzywuzzy.zip' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<access key id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret key>'
```

Comment: Thanks! It work with locally defined functions! Now looking how to call `fuzzy_test(a,b)` once to have the result computed as as column like `fuzzy_test(a,b) as distance`  and using it also in other conditions, like `...and fuzzy_test(a,b) < 0.5`